# How develop website for different different screen sizes

Tags: javascript, html, css, flask, styles

Hi I developed a blog site on my laptop. I writes it's code according to laptop screen. And on laptop screen it display good. But when I saw it on a large screen size monitor. It display so bad. I want to how I develop my site for different screen sizes without writing all code again. So can you help me

Comment: Take a look at [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media)

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/

Answer (score 0):

To make you site responsive for different screen sizes. You have to use media queries.

Yes, you can use framework like Bootstrap to achieve it easily, and under the hood they also use media queries and jQuery for responsiveness.

If you already developed you site without any CSS framework then you should go with media queries and if you want to use any framework, then you have to write you code again according to framework. (Almost, not all).

Source to learn CSS media queries -
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries